# User login status stored in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have a site which connects to an API to authenticate a users credentials. If the credentials are correct, I store a variable in the reserved variable $_SESSION

```
$_SESSION['userloggedin'] = true;
```

I then use

```
if ( $_SESSION['userloggedin'] === true ) {
    //do logged in stuff
} else {
    //redirect to login page
}
```

Although basic, from a security point of view, is there anything else I need to do if the authentication is handled through an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things you can do to secure site properly. Some suggestions are:

- Use HTTPS protocol
- Store user details properly ie. store hashed values of passwords in database
- Make sure user details are not leaked through API
- ...

But yeah it's sufficent to store the session varible which authenticates user.